# Replacing target table in Mapping Designer

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How do I replace the target in mapping designer. I have tried to delete and drag a new one there but it says it is a 'read only'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your mapping whether your target table defined as shortcut from sharable folder or direct definition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `check out` the mapping and then drag the new target. Seems to be your informatica repository is configured to handle version control. Please check out the workflow and perform the changes